# Determining predictive ability of models for readmission risks for patients

Tags: predictive-models

I am studying risk prediction models for readmissions to hospitals and during the course of my research, I came across this survey paper that evaluates various risk prediction models published in various medical journals: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t1inuv8112tnnip/Survey%20of%20Predictive%20Models%20for%20Readmission%20Risk.pdf

Towards the end of the article (page 1696), the paper states that:

> Even though the overall predictive ability of the clinical models was poor, we did find that high- and low-risk scores were associated with a clinically meaningful gradient of readmission rates.

I am a bit confused by this statement. If in practice, a high risk score from a given model is associated with high rate of readmission, doesn't it imply that the model has good predictive ability?

Comment: If, for example, very few of the predictions were low-risk or high-risk, then it would make sense to say the predictive ability of the models were poor.

Comment: That article is copyrighted, I believe, and should not be in a public dropbox.  As @dave said, the models lack predictive discrimination, i.e., have low $R^2$ or $c$-indexes (ROC areas).

Comment: Frank - the paper is available as a free download from JAMA's site: http://jama.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=1104511. I included Dropbox link as it is more convenient.

Comment: Dave and Frank - thanks for your comments. How should then one interpret the second part of that statement, that is, "we did find that high and low-risk scores were associated with a clinically meaningful gradient of readmission rates"? What's the intuition there?